# What's the maximum key length for PHP APC?

Tags: php, apc

You would think this would be super-easy to find, but I can't seem to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really don't know PHP, but it looks like values are added using [`apc_add()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apc-add.php) or [`apc_store()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apc-store.php), which take keys which are strings. I would infer that the maximum key length is therefore the maximum length of a string in PHP.

According to [PHP: Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php),

> **Note:** It is no problem for a string to become very large. PHP imposes no boundary on the size of a string; the only limit is the available memory of the computer on which PHP is running.

Comment: @Steve Clay: Agreed, and thanks for your actual answer. Very long keys are more likely to exhaust APC's allotted shared memory space (default=32M) before PHP (or even the system) runs out of memory.

Answer (score 7):

There appears to be no limitation on key size/content.

Internally, keys are initialized via the C function [apc_cache_make_user_key](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/apc/trunk/apc_cache.c?view=markup#l1063), which takes the given key string ("identifier") and stores it along with a hashed version.